# How to fast-forward and rewind an MP3 in java

Tags: java, audio, mp3

I am trying to create methods that will rewind and fast-forward an mp3 file in java. I tried using an event listener, but for the life of me, couldn't get it to work.

Wouldn't they be something like getting the current frame and then playing that file at current frame +  some amount?

Comment: What framework are you using for playing the audio? What kind of datastructure? What kind of event listener?

Comment: I am currently using jLayer and it simply imports it as a file and creates a BufferedInputStream and puts that stream into a AdvancedPlayer(contained in jLayer)